# Question update notice not showing any more

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, frontpage

The landing page of the math stack exchange used to have a feature that displayed how many new or updated questions had been asked since you last refreshed the page. Clicking on it 'refreshed' the page to show these new questions.

Two or so weeks ago, this feature has simply no longer been working for me. Was the feature removed, or is it some other problem? I am using the Chrome browser if that's worth anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On [2 March 2017](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25985) the default front page changed from the "active" ordering to the ["interesting" ordering](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/09/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/). The goal of this is to show users a list of questions that are more likely to be *interesting* to them, based on their preferences and usage history. Part of this change is the removal of the "questions with new activity" notification from the front page, since questions are no longer being ordered by activity, but some other metric.

You can still get to the old "active" ordering with new activity notifications through the ["active" ordering in the Questions tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active) (or specific tag pages).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Boo, hiss! But it seems MO is still sorted by "active" – is that right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson As far as I'm aware, only Stack Overflow and Math Stack Exchange use the "interesting" tab, largely due to their sizes. MathOverflow still uses the "active" sort as default, and I see no reason to think this would change anytime soon (or later).