# Question didn't bump

Tags: support, bumping

I edited [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1697694/660) and posted [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2219051/660) but they didn't bump.

Comment: Is it possible that you are viewing some other tab, and not active? When I look at questions tagged ([tag:extension-field]) and choose [the tab displaying recently active questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extension-field?sort=active), I see it at the top.

Comment: Thanks! I also see it at the top when I click on your link, but I don't see it if I go to http://math.stackexchange.com and choose the "interesting" option among the options "interesting", "featured", "hot", "week", "month". I just wonder why. PS: here is the link: http://math.stackexchange.com/?tab=interesting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the clarification in the comments it seems that it is not a bug - whether you see recently active questions depends on the way you view the site.

- If you go to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions then you have several tabs to choose from. If you want to see the question which have some recent activity, you have to choose the [active tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active).
- IIRC active tab used to be also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/. However this was changed not so long ago. See here for more details: [Question update notice not showing any more](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26040/question-update-notice-not-showing-any-more) and [Proposal: make the "interesting" tab the default on Math.SE homepage](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9249/proposal-make-the-interesting-tab-the-default-on-math-se-homepage/25985#25985).