# The way questions appear on the site

Tags: discussion

I have been an active member on this site for at least two years now. I have noticed this fact quite often that some days I see questions continuously from the same topic. On some days I see a group of questions which are easily solvable. On some days I find a group of questions from the topic I haven't heard before. My question is this. Is there some sort of filter or some methodology by which questions appear ? Or is this purely co incidental ? Or there are other reasons involved ?

Comment: Please add which tab you are talking about, [newest questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) or [active questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active)

Comment: newest questions

Comment: Probably it is coincidence.  Occasionally we get an over-eager editor who goes on a spree and edits lots of questions on a certain topic (perhaps adding or deleting a certain tag).  Then all those questions end up on the front page at once.  Not good.  When this happens, we point it out to the eager editor, and then the next time he knows that he should spread out his improvements over a period of days.

Answer (score 1):

This is purely coincidental, assuming that you aren't filtering by any particular tag. Newest questions are sorted by activity.

Comment: I think it probably is a coincidence. And since nobody has mentioned it, I'll also note that the [default sort](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9249/proposal-make-the-interesting-tab-the-default-on-math-se-homepage) is by "interesting" now, although I doubt it changes the likelihood of coincidences much (although it *does* probably affect the chance of seeing groups of questions about similar topics, since the algorithm is trying to show questions each individual user is interested in).