# Should a new answer bring the problem to the top?

Tags: support, answers, bumping, specific-answer

A question I have answered some half an hour ago ([Proving that all numbers are rational](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3073632/181098)) stays deep below the fold and doesn't pop up to the top of the question list. Is there any explanation to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Actually, a new answer *bumps* the question.

However, it all depends a bit on the way users view the posts.

If you look at the posts tagged [rational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers), this question is on the top if you choose the [active tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers?sort=active) - which show questions that recently had some activity. However, if you choose the [newest tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers?sort=newest), the questions are displayed there depending on the date and time when *the question* was posted. (Still, this question is visible there, since it is relatively new and this tag is not user very often.) Of course, the same general principle is true for the [active](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active) and [newest](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) tab when [viewing the questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions) - I just chose this tag as an example because of the specific post you linked to.

You can find some further details and link to more information in the [tag-info for bumping](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bumping/info).

I will add that the page https://math.stackexchange.com/ is a bit different. (For example, it does not have active or newest tab.) See also: [Proposal: make the “interesting” tab the default on Math.SE homepage](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9249).

Comment: Thanks for answering - but honestly, I do not understand. "the page https://math.stackexchange.com/ is a bit different." Different from WHAT? This is the page I use to view questions, and - yes - there are no "active" or "newest" tags there.

Comment: @W-t-P Different from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions - which is linked in the answer. (Still, even on https://math.stackexchange.com/ you have several various tabs that you can try.)

Comment: I see. I've chosen the Active tab - the question does not appear there either...

Comment: I just want to make sure that you have noticed that the title of the question has been edited in the meantime to: [Proving that if $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are rational numbers and $\sqrt{x_1}+\dots\sqrt{x_n}$ is rational, then each $\sqrt{x_i}$ is rational as well](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3073632). Do you see a question with *this* title?

Comment: @W-t-P You have to go back to the question - which had last activity about 20 minutes ago. If you are viewing 15 question per page, at the moment it is on the second page, if you are viewing 30 or 50 questions per page you will see it on the second page of the [active tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active). And some 20 minutes ago it was right at the top.